# Python simple addition issue

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, python-3.4, addition

I'm new to Python, when I'm trying to do simple addition on IDLE there is no issue except when I'm trying to add 2.3 and 2.4. Please find below the IDLE output

```
>>> 2.23+2.34
4.57
>>> 2.4+2.3
4.699999999999999
>>> a = 2.3
>>> b = 2.4
>>> a+b
4.699999999999999
>>> c =a +b
>>> c
4.699999999999999
>>> 2.1+2.6
4.7
```

2.3 and 2.4 addition returns 4.6999 instead of 4.67, is it a issue with my interpreter or anyone else can reproduce the same error. Any sort of explanation would be of great help.

Comment: Read https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: If you need exact decimal-precision, use the [`decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/decimal.html) from the standard library.